# Trouble Verifying Message RSA Signature Scheme Over Sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, rsa, digital-signature, crypto++

Im trying to send signed messaged from my server over a socket to a client. I am having trouble verifying the messages. I have tried the filtered and non filtered way based off of the code examples provided on the wiki. I have tried nearly everything I could find on Google but i'm stummped.

How can I do this signature verification scheme over sockets? I left everything I have been trying commented out just to show what I have been trying to do.

```
   SERVER:

   try
   {
      AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
      stringstream ss;
      string signature;

//      byte* signature = new byte[tdata->signer.MaxSignatureLength()];
//      if( NULL == signature )
//      {
//         throw Exception(Exception::OTHER_ERROR, "Invalid Signature");
//      }
//
//      size_t length = tdata->signer.SignMessage( rng, (const byte*) sendBuf.c_str(),
//          sendBuf.length(), signature );
      //string signature;
//    byte* message = (byte*) sendBuf.c_str();
//    SecByteBlock signature(tdata->signer.MaxSignatureLength(sendBuf.size()));
//
//    size_t signatureLen = tdata->signer.SignMessageWithRecovery(rng, message,
//             sendBuf.size(), NULL, 0, signature);
//
//    cout << "Signature Length: " << signatureLen << endl;
//    ss << signatureLen;
//    string len = ss.str();
//    string send;
//    send = (char*)signature.data();
//    send += " " + len;
      StringSource(sendBuf, true,
               new SignerFilter(rng, tdata->signer, new StringSink(signature),
                        true // putMessage
                        )// SignerFilter
                        );// StringSource

//    cout << "Signature: " << std::hex << signature << endl;
//    // Encode the message as an Integer
//    m = Integer((const byte *) sendBuf.c_str(), sendBuf.size());
//
//    //Encrypt
//    c = tdata->privateKey.CalculateInverse(rng, m);
//
//    //Turn the encrypted value into a string
//    ss << c;
//    sendBuf = ss.str();
//    ss.str("");
//    ss.clear();
//    cout << "Cipher Sent: " << sendBuf << endl;

      tdata->sockSource.Send((byte*)signature.c_str(), sizeof(signature));
```

And here is the client

```
   CLIENT:

   string signature, recovered;
   stringstream ss("");
   AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
   byte byteBuf[ 1000 ];

   try
   {
      // Retrieve message from socket
      cout << "Waiting for reply from server..." << endl;
      sockServer.Receive(byteBuf, sizeof(byteBuf));

      ss << byteBuf;
      string signature = ss.str();
      ss.str("");
      ss.clear();

//    byte sig[2048];
//    bool result = verifier.VerifyMessage( (const byte*)message.c_str(),
//        message.length(), sig, 2048 );
//
//    if( true == result )
//    {
//        cout << "Message Verified" << endl;
//    }
//    else
//    {
//        cout << "Message Verification Failed" << endl;
//    }
//    cout << endl << std::hex << "Cipher Received: " << byteBuf << endl;
//
//    SecByteBlock recovered(
//             verifier.MaxRecoverableLengthFromSignatureLength(length));
//
//    DecodingResult result = verifier.RecoverMessage(recovered, NULL, 0,
//             byteBuf, length);
//
//    if ( !result.isValidCoding )
//    {
//       throw Exception(Exception::OTHER_ERROR, "Invalid Signature");
//    }
//
//    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
//    // Use recovered message
//    size_t recoveredLen = result.messageLength;
//
//    assert(
//             0
//                      == memcmp(byteBuf, (const byte* )recovered,
//                               std::min(sizeof(byteBuf), recoveredLen)));

//     Convert message to a string
//    StringSource ss1(byteBuf, sizeof(byteBuf), true,
//             new StringSink(temp));
//
//    ss << byteBuf;
//    signature = ss.str();
//    ss.str("");
//    ss.clear();
//
//    cout << "Signature received: " << std::hex << signature << endl;
//
      StringSource(signature, true,
               new SignatureVerificationFilter(verifier,
                        new StringSink(recovered),
                        SignatureVerificationFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION
                                 | SignatureVerificationFilter::PUT_MESSAGE) // SignatureVerificationFilter
                                 );// StringSource

      cout << "Verified signature on message" << endl;
      return recovered;
//    return recovered;

//    //Convert the string to an Integer so we can calculate the inverse
//    c = Integer(recBuf.c_str());
//    r = serverKey.ApplyFunction(c);
//    cout << "r: " << r << endl;
//
//    // Recover the original message
//    size_t req = r.MinEncodedSize();
//    recovered.resize(req);
//    r.Encode((byte *) recovered.data(), recovered.size());
//    cout << "Recovered: " << recovered << endl;

   }
   catch ( Exception& e )
   {
      cerr << "caught Exception..." << endl;
      cerr << e.what() << endl;
      sockServer.ShutDown(SHUT_RDWR);
      return "";
   }
```

Comment: You should practice on a local file first, before you move onto sockets. Maybe Google [Protocol Buffers](http://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) would be helpful to help abstract away the socket details. They also work, so you won't have to worry about clearing low-level bugs in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string signature;

// ...

tdata->sockSource.Send((byte*)signature.c_str(), sizeof(signature));
```

A `std::string` is a relatively small class. My `std::string`s are 32 bytes long. So, my `sizeof(signature)` is 32.

Your `sizeof(signature)` is probably the same. And, as you know `sizeof` is a compile-time constant. It's going to be 32, or 16, or whatever, whether or not the string contains a few bytes, or a few megabytes.

What you should be doing is using `signature.size()` to determine the number of bytes to write.

Additionally, it's not clear what socket API library you're using, but with most APIs you are not guaranteed to successfully send the requested number of bytes. The request to send a given number of bytes will typically return how many bytes were written, which could be less, in which case you are required to try again. The same thing is true for reading from a socket. You have to know, in advance, how many bytes you expect to receive, and if you read fewer bytes, you have to keep reading.

It's likely that you must check the return value from `Send()` and `Receive()`, and take the appropriate action.

Comment: Thanks for noticing my string size problem. I've been stairing and switching things around so much i missed that detail somewhere along the way. I am using Crypto++ Socket API. I haven't had a problem with anything else but signature verification. I am also doing RSA encryption and decryption and that works fine. The reason I am doing signatures for the sending side is because I am trying to stop the MITM Diffie-Hellman attack, but I only have one public/private key pair. I can only cut off one side of the attack, but that is fine.

Comment: I also fixed the size problem. Still no verification using the pipelining filter methodology. Shouldn't that work?

Comment: Looks like you're also not clearing the `byteBuf` buffer. It probably contains random junk. `Receive()` is dumping bytes into it, and it is not explicitly `'\0` terminated. Note that `std::string`s, can contain null bytes, and initializing a string or a string stream from a plain buffer collects everything up to the first `'\0'`, only. In fact, that whole stringstream serves no useful purpose whatsoever. You need to know how many bytes you `Receive()`d, exactly. Period.

Comment: You sir, are the man!  Well my messages verify now, but why no recovery? I literally get nothing. hmmm.

Comment: *"...it's not clear what socket API library you're using, but with most APIs you are not guaranteed to successfully send the requested number of bytes..."* - I was thinking along those lines. Maybe Google [Protocol Buffers](http://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) would be helpful to him to help abstract away the details.

Comment: Well I have learned something. If you are going to send anything over sockets, just go ahead and encode it in, say, Base64. Make sure your buffers are memset to 0. Everything works correctly now. I actually ended up abandoning the signing part of my project because since I am doing raw RSA encryption, i can effectively "sign" it by decrypting.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with sending binary data over a socket. You just need to know exactly how many bytes are sent and received, and handle the received data correctly.

Comment: Well I was also having `\0` character issues as well in my data and who knows what else. So I just threw it through those functions and it worked. Crypto++ has a pretty steep learning curve. Thanks for making me aware of that issue as well. Idk what I would do without you guys.